# Communicating with a hardware offering a Python interface using iOS

Tags: iphone, python, objective-c, ios

I have to access a hardware component that exposes the following Python interface:

```
$ python
>>> from ***.***.***.*** import *

>>> client = Client('http://*****')

>>> client.getFirmwareVersion()
```

How I can do it?

Do I have to create new class in obj-c or I can use the python library and access the data using objective-c?

Comment: If you are down voting because the question was not written clearly (as the user is not a native English speaker), consider editing the question to make it more legible.

Comment: I think some of the original facts from that question got omitted when correcting. The OP clearly talked about a web-interface. I would suspect that he actually tries to access something using HTTP-communication and not to mix ObjectiveC with Python on the device itself.

Comment: without HTTP. I need to use two python's classes and it's methods to control the hardware. It must be on ios

Comment: How are you connecting that hardware to the iOS device?

Comment: As it stands, the question really doesn't make sense. And I dont think the English is the only problem.

Comment: it connect to lan and lan have wi-fi spot. I know device IP. - It's not a problem.

problem is:
i dont know how to use python api in iOS application

Comment: Well, there we go -> you simply connect to your device via IP (e.g. HTTP) and communicate that way. There is no need to run any Python code on the iOS device itself. Consider looking at your hardware as if it was a remote server which is to be controlled by your local (iOS) client.

Comment: but i have two python headers they have 2 classes. Maybe it need to load on hardware (i thought they must be link to project). But question open: What should i read to understand how make that connection?

Comment: @pavel.kozlov you need an Application Programming Interface that is usable via IP connectivity. As drafted in my answer HTTP would be a great choice. Talk with the hardware developers and ask them if there was a HTTP interface available to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing an important point; the hardware you are connecting actually stays entirely remote from the iOS perspective - even if it was connected via TCP/IP via a local wifi hotspot.

Have a look at [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html), that is an iOS system component that allows you to remotely connect and transmit data via TCP/IP in both directions.

Your first task will be finding a proper interface for your Python driven hardware. I would strongly suggest you to use some kind of an HTTP-interface.

Comment: Thank u.
But i have only 2 python headers. that's all I found on the hardware's website.

Maybe i need to create web-interface based on it? Like i transmit string - hardware transmit string back?

Comment: i read u comment after my comment. Thank u

Comment: Exactly, you will have to build that yourself then, but on the hardware itself and not within iOS. From iOS you then remotely connect and trigger your requests/actions.

Comment: .. I am really glad we got you on the right track :D

Comment: yep, i all time think how to use python methods in app. I'm really happy that u has explained it to me. And one more question: it's really hard to understand my bad english?